# SQL: how to calculates the categories of value of specific column?

Tags: mysql

i have a table which its schema as follow:
[image]

i want to calculates how many kinds of product and how many quantity which user had bought between 2016-07-01 to 2016-07-30, the result would be like follow:

[image]

how to get this result by SQL statement? thanks~

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_name
       COUNT(DISTINCT ordered_product),
       SUM(ordered_quantity)
FROM t
WHERE (ordered_time BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2016-07-30')
GROUP BY user_name;
```